# How memory address is created

Tags: c++, c, memory, computer-science, ram

I'm a little bit confused about memory addresses, to my knowledge each memory address is of the size 1 byte (8 bits) each has it's own hexadecimal address 0x122.., now when we store let's say a 32 bit int that takes 4 bytes, now does the computer combine each 1 byte address (0x123, 0x124..) to form one new 4 byte address.

Comment: The computer does not combine each 1 byte address to form one new 4 byte address.  It uses the 1 byte address of the first byte of the 4 byte word (`int`) as the address of the entire word.

Comment: You're confusing the size of the address with the size of the thing stored at (actually starting at) that address.

Comment: 32-bits are 4 bytes and they are stored in 4 sequential addresses. You point the first address and other are +1/+2/+3. The representation of 32 bit in 4 bytes depends of endianess of CPU.

Comment: An address is an address: how *much* memory it is pointing to depends on the context.

Comment: Each byte *has* an address, but that address is much bigger than 8 bits. If the size of an *address* were 8 bits, your memory could only hold 256 bytes.

Comment: So it refers to the first address just like arrays but in arrays for example the last address is null, so the computer know it's the end of the address, how does that works for int, how does it know it should stop at 4 bytes not 5

Comment: @droppre, "*in arrays for example the last address is null*" -- not in the slightest.  Maybe you are thinking of C strings, where the semantic *value* of the string is marked by a `char` with *value* 0, often called a "null terminator".  That has nothing to do with addresses, nor with arrays in general.

Comment: You need to find a better book to learn from.

Comment: The program does not, in general, know where object boundaries are from looking at memory.  Objects are a higher-level abstraction that exists mostly in source code, not in computer memory.  The program knows the address of the of an object because it is responsible for tracking that, or because it is told.  It knows the size of the object based on its data type, which the program is also responsible for tracking, or needs to be told.  These two properties make up the identity of an object.

Comment: Yes exactly i was thinking in terms of char arrays in c. so it's by design know how much a data type use memory, thank you for clearing the confusion.

Comment: You should read up on micro-controller design or digital circuitry for information on how addresses are created and how they work.

Comment: *32-bits are 4 bytes...* Not always. I can think of at least one major computer where 32 bits was one byte.

Answer (score 2):

A memory address by itself is the location of a single byte. To access objects of more than one byte, we use both an address and a *type*.

To specify the address of an object with multiple bytes, we use the address of the first byte.

In C, the number of bytes in an object is known from its type. The semantics of C are specified so that all expressions referring to an object have a type, and it is known from that type how many bytes to access.

Answer (score 0):

A picture might help.  Assume a 4-byte integers `0x01234567`.  Given a starting address `0x1000`, it would be stored as

```
Little-endian        Big-endian
-------------        ----------
              +----+
      0x1000: | 67 | :0x1003
              +----+
      0x1001: | 45 | :0x1002
              +----+
      0x1002: | 23 | :0x1001
              +----+
      0x1003: | 01 | :0x1000
              +----+
```

Each byte still has a unique address. In a little-endian system, the least-significant byte is the addressed byte, while in a big-endian system the most-significant byte is the addressed byte.

If you have a second integer `0x89abcdef`, it could be laid out as

```
Little-endian        Big-endian
-------------        ----------
              +----+
      0x1000: | 67 | :0x1003
              +----+
      0x1001: | 45 | :0x1002
              +----+
      0x1002: | 23 | :0x1001
              +----+
      0x1003: | 01 | :0x1000
              +----+
      0x1004: | ef | :0x0FFF
              +----+
      0x1005: | cd | :0x0FFE
              +----+
      0x1006: | ab | :0x0FFD
              +----+
      0x1007: | 89 | :0x0FFC
              +----+
```

The starting addresses for the two objects are 4 bytes apart - `0x1000` and `0x1004` in the little-endian layout, `0x0FFC` and `0x1000` in the big-endian layout.